PowerAutomate workflow to MS Teams channel does not return the 403 status when quota is exceeded
I recently started testing a workflow that is using the "Post to channel when a webhook request is received" template to send messages to a Teams channel.
When I send a message after the quota is exceeded the workflow is returning a HTTP Status of 202, rather than the 403 status that is documented when the quota is reached.
This leaves me with no way to determine whether the Teams channel actually processed the message.
Is there any way to determine from an HTTP client that the quota has been reached and message are no longer being posted to the channel?
Here is the graphical representation of the flow:


Can you show us the result of a run where you’re seeing this behavior?

The status Power Automate web site run history Post to a channel when a webhook request is received shows it returning a 403 status with a message that states "Out of call volume quota.  Quota will be replenished...." . However,  the response content to returned from the HttpCient.PostAsync is empty and the status returned is 202.

Sorry, but you haven’t answered my question, show us your flow.

Before sending the message, you can implement a check to see if the quota has been reached. This can be done by keeping track of the number of messages sent within a certain period and comparing it to the quota limit.

Sorry Skin, I guess I don't understand what you want to see, do you want the code for all the steps?

Nivedipa-MSFT, I don't think this is the answer when there no way to count messages sent in previous sessions or my other users to the same webhook.

You can create a logging system that records each message sent to the webhook. This log can include details such as the timestamp, user, and message content. By analyzing this log, you can track the number of messages sent over time.
